Reference for "Man is the best computer we can put aboard a spacecraft... and the only one that can be mass-produced with unskilled labor"
You can find this quote on a lot of websites :
"Man is the best computer we can put aboard a spacecraft... and the only one that can be mass-produced with unskilled labor" with Wernher von Braun as author.
On Wikiquote, it appears on the talk page (i.e.: not in the main article) in the "unsourced" section : https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Talk:Wernher_von_Braun
On this website, there are details saying : "Werner von Braun, 1963; Talking with John F. Kennedy"
Is there some published reference about this quote ?
Thank you

I have no proof of this (so I'm not posting it as an answer) but it seems to me quite likely that this quote is a garbled version of Isaac Asimov's story The Feeling of Power, misattributed to Werner von Braun. The story indeed covers the "mass-produced with unskilled labor" aspect, and ends by mentioning manned missiles (relevant since Werner von Braun was a rocket scientist).

Guenter Wendt claims that von Braun said it in a NASA budget meeting http://www.brevardfl.gov/docs/default-source/historical-commission-docs/not-508-oral-history/wendt-guenter-transcript.pdf?sfvrsn=abdb99d7_3 (page 11).

I have not been able to find  primary source for this quote - as the OP notes, the phrase is quoted on a vast number of web-pages, normally just attributed to "Werner von Braun" without any date or citation.
I was, however, able to find a seemingly plausible secondary source. Guenter Wendt, the aeronautics engineer who worked with von Braun in the Apollo program, and was affectionately known as "the fuehrer of the launch tower", claimed that von Braun told him that he made this statement in a budget meeting. In an oral history of the space program made by the Brevard County Government, Wendt is recalled his memories of von Braun charming the budgetary commissions:

And one of my other famous stories from Von Braun, I picked up from him
himself one time.  He went to a budget hearing and they said, "You
know  in our age  of computers we should really eliminate the costly
man in space program because we can do everything with computers." And
Von Braun had really a nice prepared answer for that. He says,
"Ladies and gentlemen, you got to understand the best computer in the world is the human brain and it's the only piece of equipment that
can be mass produced by unskilled labor." He again, he got his money
for the program. He had a good, good way of doing it.

If this is true, then von Braun's answer should be recorded in the minutes of the meeting, which would represent an excellent primary source. Until this is uncovered, however, I think we will have to be content with Wendt's memory of what von Braun told him.
